# Inject customer-specific data into Outlook add-in

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

For our add-in, we need some data that will be different on a per-customer basis, such as a customer ID, base URL (changes based on region/environment), API key, etc. We will need this data in order to contact some of our external microservices.

We've looked into RoamingSettings, and that seems to be a good way to save this customer data for later use, but this would only be possible AFTER our data gets injected and is available to the add-in for saving.

We've looked into this question and its corresponding answers: [Read parameters from Outlook 365 Add-In manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755994/read-parameters-from-outlook-365-add-in-manifest). Michael Zlatkovsky's answer, regarding appending an encoded string with that data to the add-in's start URL in the XML manifest, and later grabbing that URL with JavaScript and decoding/parsing that query string seems to be our best option yet.

Is there a standardized or more common way of injecting data into an add-in?

Comment: I assume your service does not require authentication? If not, why can't you create an endpoint which is automatically requested when loading the add-in with user's e-mail as a parameter. Then, on backend, check this e-mail in your DB and in the response place all the data you need. Boom - you have user's data in your add-in.

Comment: There isn't a standard way of doing this. If you can modify the manifest per customer basis, then the query parameter is a fine way to do this. If you can't then Niko's idea of getting the e-mail and keying off that may work too.